# Swift how to update the Search result when touch return key

Tags: swift, uisearchcontroller

I Swift, i make a Search View using `UISearcheController` and `UISearcheResultUpdating`

and i update the result with `func updateSearchResultsForSearchController`

```
if self.searchController?.searchBar.text.lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding(NSUTF32StringEncoding) > 0 {  
        let searchBarText = self.searchController!.searchBar.text
        var arrResult = DFManager.GetResult(searchBarText)
        self.results?.addObjectsFromArray(arrResult)            
        // Reload a table with results.
        self.searchResultsController?.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

But that is result always updating when i type char by char, it make this app slowly. I want this result only update when type return key?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

        //do something
        searchBar.resignFirstResponder() //hide keyboard

    }
```

And dont forget to add the searchBar delegate:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

   @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        searchBar.delegate = self
   }

}
```